# Hiker's Cabin Mystery | Pt. XVI

Tags: cipher

It's been a *whiiiiiile* since we've had one of these!

---

You continue on through the forest and enter the labyrinth, once more. And again, you find a small piece of paper: `73-86-85-53-8-7`

There's also a fairly futuristic keyboard lying on the ground. You guess that you must type in a passphrase in order to advance. Better get to it!

---

**Current Points:**
Joshua Bizley -- <strike>24</strike> <strike>19</strike> 14 points

Shoover -- <strike>15</strike> <strike>40</strike> 109 points

Omega Krypton -- <strike>40</strike> <strike>60</strike> 67 points

Jan Ivan -- 100 points

El-Guest -- 65 points

SEE PART XI FOR INFORMATION ON HOW POINTS WORK

Comment: rot13(Qba'g unir zhpu bs na vqrn rkprcg gung pbairefvba gb purzvpny ryrzrag flzobyf tvirf n qrprag yrggre cbby?)

Comment: If the 6 should be an 8 @Skynet_0 could be right

Comment: @Bananenkopp - Oops... It should be an 8! I'll fix that immediately!

Comment: Okay but how does the futuristic keyboard hint have anything to do with <removed to avoid spoilers>? I've been going down the road of: languages we might expect everyone to speak in the future, ways that a keyboard could be rearranged in the future, base-X that we might expect to be used in the future... that just seems like a red herring now, and that means you literally just had 6 numbers. There is a lot you can turn any six numbers into, and I can imagine someone else finding a word that is just as objectively true as the actual solution, which fits the context just as much.

Comment: @JoshuaBizley - It has nothing to do with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments from Skynet_0 and Bananenkopp, we see that

> When translated from numbers to their periodic table abbreviations, the code 73-86-85-53-8-7 becomes Ta-Rn-At-I-O-N.

The passcode may therefore be

> TARNATION.

Comment: Absolutely correct!!!

Comment: +65 points.....